# grunt configuration for replacing image file references in html

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I am using grunt to process my web app, and minify stuff.

So grunt minifies my image files perfectly and puts them into the image folder, etc in the dist folder, but it doesn't replace the references for those files in the html files.

Comment: Which plugin do you use? Grunt itself doesn't do any image manipulation.

Comment: ok i think usemin is the one to be configured for this, still researching...

Comment: Imagemin doesn't replace the paths, you have to do it yourself. It would be best to use a temporary folder for your image urls that contains the minified images and keep the original ones somewhere else.